# Postfix not delivering from external senders and not logging anything

Tags: postfix

Some semi-recent upgrades must have broken my postfix+dovecot configuration, but I'm having problems finding out what the cause is.

My domain is `simendsjo.me` with the MX record `mail.simendsjo.me`.

I can send mail to both local and external recipients, and it delivers mail from internal mailboxes.

The problem is that mail from external senders isn't delivered, and nothing is logged at all.
The external sender also doesn't receive any errors.

I have no idea where to ever start looking as nothing is logged at all when external mail is sent to my server.

So the first issue would be: How can I turn on some debug messages for postfix?

I've tried:

```
debug_peer_level = 2
debug_peer_list = simendsjo.me
```

.. And `_level = 999` and `_list = gmail.com` where I'm trying to send emails from.
but nothing is logged.

When sending mails from a local mailbox (but from an outside computer, not localhost), a lot is logged.

I don't have any rules in iptables either.

Any ideas how I can get some debug messages for postfix?

Comment: If you're not getting anything logged, then external mailservers aren't even connecting. Check your MX records and your firewall rules (and your ISP firewall, if any). Since you've chosen to hide your domain name, nobody else can help you with that.

Comment: But if external mail servers isn't connecting, shouldn't I get an 'undeliverable' message back? I added my domainname, simendsjo.me.

Comment: That depends on the type of error. If it's a transient error, the sender will try again and only return an error message after a configurable time.

Comment: Ah, so I just need to add an smtp on port 25 and all is good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mailserver isn't accepting connections on port 25:

```
[jenny@sameen ~]$ telnet mail.simendsjo.me 25
Trying 151.236.221.202...
telnet: connect to address 151.236.221.202: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed that :/ That what happens when you secure the box and forget to open up for the outside world just enough.

Comment: Well, at least it couldn't be abused as a spam relay :-)